# How to set design of multiple button in same xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have created a file and named as 'button_ui.xml' then set the design of button using 'item'. and apply it in main activity. My question is that can we set different design for multiple buttons in same xml file like css where we set 'btn-primary', 'btn-default' etc class and then in html we just use class for specific design of button can we do same thing in android. If yes then how can we?

Comment: use styles in res/value/styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style file which is addressed in res/value/styles

You can use this type in style file

```
  <style name="ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/_250sdp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/_60sdp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
        <item name="android:autoSizeStepGranularity">2sp</item>
        <item name="android:autoSizeMaxTextSize">@dimen/_25ssp</item>
        <item name="android:autoSizeMinTextSize">@dimen/_5ssp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/_15sdp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/_40sdp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:paddingHorizontal">@dimen/_5sdp</item>
    </style>
```

And this style apply in main.xml Button like this

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/emailbtn"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="CONTINUE" />
```